# RewriteRule running after Require test failed which rewrites 403.shtml to website content instead of error message

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache-2.4, httpd.conf

When a request gets denied due to `require all denied`, it first gets routed to the ErrorDocument 403.shtml but then that gets rewritten rather than stopping there and the site content actually gets served up (albeit with a 403 status code).

We've boiled it down to a very simple test case

In .htaccess in the root of the site put the following.

```
Require all denied 
RewriteRule .* test.txt [L]
```

In test.txt in the root of the site put the following:

```
You shouldn't see this text here but if you are it's because of the RewriteRule running after Require all denied gets processed
```

I confirmed commenting out the RewriteRule causes the `Require` Directive to behave as expected.

Here's some relevant `LogLevel trace8` output:

```
authorization result of Require all denied: denied
authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied
AH01630: client denied by server configuration
auth phase 'check access' gave status 403
mod_rewrite.c: strip per-dir prefix: /home/path-to-site/403.shtml -> 403.shtml
mod_rewrite.c: applying pattern '.*' to uri '403.shtml'
mod_rewrite.c: rewrite '403.shtml' -> 'test.txt'
```

EDIT:

One thing that's odd about this issue is that it started occurring all of a sudden.  It's almost like something changed on the server like something that would affect the ErrorDocument directives or their behavior, but I can't think of anything we might have changed that could cause that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out ErrorDocument directives got added whereas there weren't any before.  This change is what caused it to stop working.

For example:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /401.shtml
ErrorDocument 403 /403.shtml
```